# WKWebView can not load url of flash message

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, flash-message

```
WKWebView *wb = [WKWebView new];
[wb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://file8a445fb7811e.iamh5.cn/v3/idea/u5UfsotV?suid=ohAJ7wa8J4S-rj0SFOVmrDhOBotM&from=singlemessage"]]];
```

This urlStr is a flash URL. It stops after load 99%. How do I fix it?
I tried to use UIWebview, it worked perfectly, but WKWebView not.

Comment: Did you check with SFSafariViewController? What's the result

Comment: I understood that your issue is not with any other but  with WKWebview. Just to figure out I asked above question

Comment: @SivajeeBattina  Thks, but i want to figure it out use WKWebView.

Comment: Understood. Did you implement delegate methods for loading? Any error you are getting?

Comment: I found the question,  it was my custom URLProtocol.

Comment: Do you mean, you found the answer?

Comment: YES, the bug was in my custom URLProtocol

Comment: Cool, you got the answer

Comment: But what the actual bug was? So other people could check that case too.